# Completed Process object doesnt produce output

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

So I've created a simply python script that runs a shell script via the subprocess library as such:

```
import subprocess
test = subprocess.run("testshell.sh", shell=True, capture_output=True)
```

The shell script just echos "Hello World!"

```
echo "Hello World!"
```

I try to grab the stdout in the python script

```
print("stdout: " + str(test.stdout))
```

but it always produces

```
stdout: b''
```

I know that I could use `subprocess.check_output()` but this also doesnt work and I need to add arguments

From what I understand, I should be getting "Hello World!" back from stdout. Any ideas how to grab the output or why its not working would be appreciated

Comment: Print value returned from `test.check_returncode()` and see if the shell script ran successfully. You should probably be checking this in any case.

Comment: I get a return code of 0 which is think is a good thing?

Comment: Yes, that means it ran OK. If the return code was non-zero, calling it would have raised a `CalledProcessError`. You're right, the results you're getting are a mystery. How are you running the Python script?

Comment: I have it open in VSCode and I just hit the run button. Even when I run it in command prompt via "python script.py" I get the blank stdout

Comment: Running it the way you are through `subprocess` is like running `testshell.sh` at the command prompt. What happens if you do that?

Comment: it works file if i run testshell.sh in the command prompt.  I get the "Hello World!" out put

Comment: Perhaps the output is being written to `stderr`. The only other thing I can suggest is to use `subprocess.Popen()` directly — `run()` is just a wrapper around that.